# Named arguments in routing in Express.js

Tags: javascript, rest, express, url-routing

I can't seem to find information about this anywhere.

I want to be able to do requests like this: `url/list/message=hello?id=1234`

But like I've said, I haven't been able to find *any* information on how to do this in Express.

My initial guess was to do this:

```
app.put('/list/message=:msg?id=:id', function (req, res) { ... });
```

But this doesn't quite work. Is there any way to do this at all in Express?

Comment: `url/list/message=hello?id=1234` looks quite unusual. Don't you mean `url/list/hello?id=1234`? Have a look at http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.param

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is generally called a *query string*, and we have a powerful URL parsing library in node to handle that for us.

Try this:

```
require('url');
...
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

Then, you can use `query.id` and get `1234`, IF you change your route to this:

```
app.put('/list/message=:msg', function (req, res) { ... });
```

Ideally, you should check that `query.id` exists before attempting to read from it. I would also recommend against using an `message=:msg`. Instead, I would rewrite the whole thing as

```
app.put('/list/:id', function (req, res) {
  var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var query = url_parts.query;
  if (query.message) {...}
});
```

which is a slightly different structure than you have currently, but is more in line with how a great deal of APIs handle their routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. What you can do is:

```
app.put('/list/message/:msg', function (req, res) {
  var msg = req.params.msg;

  var url = require('url');
  var id = url.parse(req.url, true).query.id;    
});
```

Your URL will look like this: url/list/message/hello?id=1234